# Get GPS Location in a Broadcast Receiver/or Service to Broadcast Receiver data transfer

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android.
I want to get GPS  Location  in a broadcast receiver but it shows an error.

My code is :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // errors in getSystemService method
    LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);
    Location loc = locManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Log.d(" **location**", " location" + loc.getLatitude());
}
```

Questions :

1. Is it possible to get GPS Location data in Broadcast receiver?
2. Another alternative way I tried so far was to use a service which is invoked by the Broadcast receiver. The service can get GPS data, but how can I get it in the Broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From BroadcastReceiver I could not start Location Manager as well. So I started a service on BroadcastReceiver and in that service I manipulated Location Manager. I think I found this solution in Android development documentation. You also can start Activity instead of Service.

Here is the code of switch to Service on BroadcastReceiver:

**write this in `onReceive` method**

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("locateRequest", "locateRequest"); // if you want pass parameter from here to service
    serviceIntent.putExtra("queryDeviceNumber", results[1]);
    context.startService(serviceIntent); //start service for get location
```

Answer (score 29):

yes both of them are possible.

your service with a timer to send request to location receiver in periods of time:

```
public class SrvPositioning extends Service {

    // An alarm for rising in special times to fire the
    // pendingIntentPositioning
    private AlarmManager alarmManagerPositioning;
    // A PendingIntent for calling a receiver in special times
    public PendingIntent pendingIntentPositioning;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        alarmManagerPositioning = (AlarmManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentToFire = new Intent(
                ReceiverPositioningAlarm.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM);
        intentToFire.putExtra(ReceiverPositioningAlarm.COMMAND,
                ReceiverPositioningAlarm.SENDER_SRV_POSITIONING);
        pendingIntentPositioning = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intentToFire, 0);
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        try {
            long interval = 60 * 1000;
            int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
            long timetoRefresh = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            alarmManagerPositioning.setInexactRepeating(alarmType,
                    timetoRefresh, interval, pendingIntentPositioning);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "error running service: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "error running service: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.alarmManagerPositioning.cancel(pendingIntentPositioning);
        ReceiverPositioningAlarm.stopLocationListener();
    }
}
```

your receiver with a listener. listener can be used in your activity to be notified that a new location is ready for you:

```
public class ReceiverPositioningAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String COMMAND = "SENDER";
    public static final int SENDER_ACT_DOCUMENT = 0;
    public static final int SENDER_SRV_POSITIONING = 1;
    public static final int MIN_TIME_REQUEST = 5 * 1000;
    public static final String ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM =
                    "org.mabna.order.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM";
    private static Location currentLocation;
    private static Location prevLocation;
    private static Context _context;
    private String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    private static Intent _intent;
    private static LocationManager locationManager;
    private static LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            try {
                String strStatus = "";
                switch (status) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STARTED";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED";
                    break;
                default:
                    strStatus = String.valueOf(status);
                    break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(_context, "Status: " + strStatus,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(_context, "***new location***",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gotLocation(location);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };

    // received request from the calling service
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "new request received by receiver",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        _context = context;
        _intent = intent;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                    MIN_TIME_REQUEST, 5, locationListener);
            Location gotLoc = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            gotLocation(gotLoc);
        } else {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "please turn on GPS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            t.show();
            Intent settinsIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            settinsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            _context.startActivity(settinsIntent);
        }
    }

    private static void gotLocation(Location location) {
        prevLocation = currentLocation == null ? null : new Location(
                currentLocation);
        currentLocation = location;
        if (isLocationNew()) {
            OnNewLocationReceived(location);
            Toast.makeText(_context, "new location saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopLocationListener();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isLocationNew() {
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (prevLocation == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (currentLocation.getTime() == prevLocation.getTime()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void stopLocationListener() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        Toast.makeText(_context, "provider stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    // listener ----------------------------------------------------
    static ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener> arrOnNewLocationListener = 
            new ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener>();

    // Allows the user to set a OnNewLocationListener outside of this class
    // and react to the event.
    // A sample is provided in ActDocument.java in method: startStopTryGetPoint
    public static void setOnNewLocationListener(
            OnNewLocationListener listener) {
        arrOnNewLocationListener.add(listener);
    }

    public static void clearOnNewLocationListener(
            OnNewLocationListener listener) {
        arrOnNewLocationListener.remove(listener);
    }

    // This function is called after the new point received
    private static void OnNewLocationReceived(Location location) {
        // Check if the Listener was set, otherwise we'll get an Exception
        // when we try to call it
        if (arrOnNewLocationListener != null) {
            // Only trigger the event, when we have any listener
            for (int i = arrOnNewLocationListener.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                arrOnNewLocationListener.get(i).onNewLocationReceived(
                        location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

an interface for listener:

```
import android.location.Location;

public interface OnNewLocationListener {
    public abstract void onNewLocationReceived(Location location);
}
```

in your activity for getting just one point:

```
protected void btnGetPoint_onClick() {
    Intent intentToFire = new Intent(
            ReceiverPositioningAlarm.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM);
    intentToFire.putExtra(ReceiverPositioningAlarm.COMMAND,
            ReceiverPositioningAlarm.SENDER_ACT_DOCUMENT);
    sendBroadcast(intentToFire);
    OnNewLocationListener onNewLocationListener = new OnNewLocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNewLocationReceived(Location location) {
            // use your new location here then stop listening
            ReceiverPositioningAlarm.clearOnNewLocationListener(this);
        }
    };
    // start listening for new location
    ReceiverPositioningAlarm
            .setOnNewLocationListener(onNewLocationListener);
}
```

**edit:**

if you want to start service in your activity:

```
this.startService(new Intent(this, SrvPositioning.class));
```

similarly you can define a listener in your service to receive locations found by receiver

**Edit**

Add the following lines in Manifest

```
<service
            android:name="org.mabna.order.services.SrvPositioning"
            android:enabled="true" />

<receiver android:name="org.mabna.order.receivers.ReceiverPositioningAlarm" >

            <!-- this Broadcast Receiver only listens to the following intent -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.mabna.order.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Just wondering, have you measured how much battery is consumed on this approach (1 minute updates) and if you have a LocationListener always active (not for GPS but for Network).

Comment: Thanks alot.One more question..If I did not start the sevice from any activity,then will the service automatically fire after the given time or dist. limits??

Comment: I think you have to start service in an Activity. Search about it :)

Comment: and pls tell me one more thing...what do you mean by "in your activity for getting just one point:"...?!? the caption of your 4th coding block...

Comment: write that code in your activity to get one point from listener. it is about using the listener.

Comment: The problem I am facing is the gps is on as the service runs in background.Hence there is a huge drainage of battery.

Comment: GPS checkbox in settings is not important. The method `stopLocationListener()` stops your gps and it does not use gps hardware until the next request for new point.

Comment: hello  breceivemail..there is one more problem.The onLocationchange fires after 60s as mentioned within the service but not after 5s as mentioned in the broadcast reciever.I want the on location change fire according to the time in  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates .Any way to do that?

Comment: @kgandroid change the `long interval = 60 * 1000;` in `SrvPositioning`

Comment: public static final int MIN_TIME_REQUEST = 5 * 1000;..You have defined this in the broadcast reciever...within the     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,MIN_TIME_REQUEST, 5, locationListener);...hence the locationmanager must fire at an interval of 5s...but this is not happening..instead the onLocationchange is fired after 60s as mentioned in the interval of service...my question why this is happening??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904061/call-a-asynctask-when-location-is-changed

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:**
 Open **AndroidManifest.xml** and add the broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Util.GpsConnectorReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
             <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

**STEP 2:** create activity with dialog theme:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.ActivityDialogGps"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.Dialog"></activity>
```

**STEP 3:**
Make a BroadcastReceiver Class named **GpsConnectorReceiver**

```
public class GpsConnectorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityCheck .class);
                context.startService(pushIntent);
    }
}}
```

**STEP 4:** Make another service class named **ConnectivityCheck** :

```
public class ConnectivityCheck extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (!checkConnection()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityDialogInternet.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(dialogIntent);
    }
    stopSelf();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private boolean checkConnection() {
     final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}}
```

**STEP 5:** create a activity called **ActivityDialogGps**

```
public class ActivityDialogGps extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_gps);
}}
```

**STEP 6:** When Gps connection is turned off **ActivityDialogGps** called and show the dialog: