# Passing parameters between service and activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, bundle

Code for passing float value from service to activity:

```
call.putExtra("floatvalue", fv);
call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(call);
```

Code for getting float value in the activity:

```
Bundle extras=new Bundle();
float value = extras.getFloat("floatvalue");
```

The problem is no matter what is passed as the float value from the service, I get only 0.0 in the activity.

What is the problem with the code?

**EDIT**

I changed the code in the activity to

```
Bundle extras=new Bundle();
extras=getIntent().getExtras();
float value = extras.getFloat("floatvalue");
```

It didnt work.

Comment: have u added  `extras = getIntent().getExtras();`  before getting value from bundle ?

Comment: As ρяσѕρєя K mentioned, you should get your extras from intent in onStartCommand, not construct the new one.

Comment: new Bundle is empty, as it is new...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK - I tried it now, doesn't seem to be working. It's still 0.

Comment: @Torcellite : first make sure you are trying this code in onCreate method and if u are getting still null then also try as `float value=getIntent().getFloatExtra("floatvalue",0);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yeah, it's in the onCreate method of the activity. "getFloatExtra()" requires two parameters, the string value and a default float value. If I set the float value, to 0 or 1, then "value" becomes only 0 or 1. Not what was passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
float value =  getIntent().getFloatExtra("floatvalue", 0.0f);
```

Since you added the float to your intent before starting it, you should get the float from that intent not from the bundle.

Comment: In a service it is better to get intent.getFloat from onStartCommand, since onStartCommand can be called several times, but onCreate only once a lifecycle.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is answering OP's question? This answer was flagged due to length.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange can u please clarify what you just said?

Comment: Nader, please expand your answer with a short explanation as to why this piece of code would solve the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: @NaderAyyad I got this error `The method getFloat(String) is undefined for the type Intent`

Comment: @NaderAyyad `getIntent()` only has `getFloatExtra(String string, float defaultValue)` when I pass the parameters as `getFloatExtra("floatvalue", 0);` I get the value set to only 0.

Answer (score 1):

Define a listener in your service like this:

```
// listener ----------------------------------------------------
static ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener> arrOnNewLocationListener =
        new ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener>();

// Allows the user to set a OnNewLocationListener outside of this class and
// react to the event.
// A sample is provided in ActDocument.java in method: startStopTryGetPoint
public static void setOnNewLocationListener(
        OnNewLocationListener listener) {
    arrOnNewLocationListener.add(listener);
}

public static void clearOnNewLocationListener(
        OnNewLocationListener listener) {
    arrOnNewLocationListener.remove(listener);
}

// This function is called after the new point received
private static void OnNewLocationReceived(float myValue) {
    // Check if the Listener was set, otherwise we'll get an Exception when
    // we try to call it
    if (arrOnNewLocationListener != null) {
        // Only trigger the event, when we have any listener
        for (int i = arrOnNewLocationListener.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arrOnNewLocationListener.get(i).onNewLocationReceived(
                    myValue);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And register it in your Activity like this:

```
 OnNewLocationListener onNewLocationListener = new OnNewLocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewLocationReceived(float myValue) {

                //use your value here

                MyService.clearOnNewLocationListener(this);
            }
        };

        // start listening for new location
        MyService.setOnNewLocationListener(
                onNewLocationListener);
```

For more information look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709140/779408

Comment: How is this related to my question? I'm just trying to pass a primitive float value.

Comment: @Torcellite you must customize it. I changed it. look at it again.

Comment: Torcellite's question is how to pass parameter from service to a "to be newly created activity".  The answer is how to pass parameter or anything to a already running activity.